# Django. form_valid()

Tags: python, django

Возможно вопрос глупый, но можете прокоментировать, что делают эти методы и что такое `super()` и что оно делает тут?

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    super().form_valid(form)


def form_valid(self, form):    
   self.object = form.save()
   return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Прежде, чем браться за Django, стоит выучить Python хотя бы в основах.

Comment: Прежде, чем отвечать, стоит вам стоит подумать, нужны ли мне ваши советы? Я задал вопрос не для того, чтобы мне давали советы.   П.С со временем сильно забыл пайтон, а код джанговский. Его я не очень понял

Comment: @thomasz нельзя забыть то, что хорошо знал. Вы обманываете нас, при чем - в наглой форме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я вижу, это "выдернуто" из какого-то класса. 
1. `def form_valid(self, form):` - функция, которая "принимает": 
**self** - ссылку на саму себя
**form** - переменную

2. `super().form_valid(form)` - вызов метода из родительского класса.

`def form_valid(self, form)` - см. выше
`self.object = form.save()` - присваивает переменной "сохранение данных формы";
`return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)` - возвращает результат выполнения функции.